# Query on ACE framework

Tags: c++, linux, ace

Of late, I am facing a problem with a code snippet which doesn't return expected values and this is causing an application to fail.

The code is built on Redhat linux 7.1 using the following command -

```
g++ ace-test.cpp -I<path-to-ace-6.2-root> -L<path-to-ace-6.2-root>/ace/Linux -g -lACE
```

The code snippet being built is pasted below -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "ace/MEM_Addr.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* []) {

        ACE_MEM_Addr addr ;

        cout << "ACE_MEM_Addr::addr.get_host_name() " << addr.get_host_name() << endl ;

}
```

On execution, the code prints the following line

```
ACE_MEM_Addr::addr.get_host_name() **unknown**
```

on a system running linux which was recently patched.

On a different system which was not patched, the same code returns the correct hostname.

I am trying to figure out which patch caused this problem, but couldn't make much progress.

If someone can please extend a bit of help, would greatly appreciate it.

If required, I can share the list of patches which were applied.

Comment: Try running your program under `strace` to see what it does.

Comment: Thanks ! Attempting it shortly

Comment: Hi @mepomene, Strace proved really useful ! Many thanks ! From comparing the system calls made, I see that the working version of code is reading entries from /etc/hosts whereas the "broken" version is checking ipv6 configuration. Any thoughts on what could potentially cause it? URL shows a comparison of strace outputs <img src="http://www.Imgur.com/1iPblC5"; width="100" height="100"> Thanks once again for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to find the culprit.

Here are the entries in /etc/nsswitch.conf:

hosts:      files dns - **(On the host without patches)**

versus

hosts:      files dns myhostname - **(On the host which was patched)**

Removal of the **myhostname** entry in the latter fixed the problem.

Associated RHEL knowledge base entry -

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2766251

Thanks a bunch for all the help !